# After click on button prevent reloading the page

Tags: javascript, button, refresh, intervals

So, my page automatically reloads after 20 seconds:

```
window.setInterval('refresh()', 20000);     
function refresh() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

So I've added a button and contidion, if its true, page will reload.

```
if(siteRefreshButton === true){
    window.setInterval('refresh()', 20000);     
function refresh() {
    window.location.reload();
}

function siteRefresh(){
    siteRefreshButton = !siteRefreshButton;
    console.log(siteRefreshButton);
}
```

My guess is, that after refresh, another interval starts before it can check if siteRefreshButton is true or false.
Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check your condition inside the `refresh` function.

```
var siteRefreshButton = true

function refresh() {
  if (siteRefreshButton) {
    window.location.reload()
  }
}

function siteRefresh() {
  siteRefreshButton = !siteRefreshButton
  console.log(siteRefreshButton)
}

window.setInterval('refresh()', 20000)
```